# What happens to my MQ if my application get down after send message to biztalk

Tags: biztalk, communication, mq

I'm new to Biztalk and I have a doubt about the status of my message. For example My application(A) reads input from client, formats and places it to a MQ (IBM).Biztalk server will read message from my MQ and probably send it to other client(B). My question is If my application(A) and my MQ server is down after pushing the message to Biztalk..will the message still resides in Biztalk or will it get discorded?

What is the result if biztalk is down after owning the message? will it still hold the message?

What is the result if biztalk own the message but the consumer application(B) is down? will biztalk will

hold the message till the application(B) read the message once it is up?

This might be simple question for experts but as a newbie I'm worried about it. Thanks for your clarification in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If application A successfully pushes the message to the queue, then crashes, the message is still in the queue.  At that point, it doesn't matter what 'state' application A is in, the message is now owned by WMQ and will be delivered to destination.

BizTalk will still read the message, completely unaware that application A may have crashed.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is If my application(A) and my MQ server is down after
>   pushing the message to Biztalk

Once the message is in the Queue, Application A no longer has control over the message. So if A crashes nothing will happen to the message pushed to the queue.

> What is the result if biztalk is down after owning the message? will
>   it still hold the message?

Microsoft BizTalk Server actually installs several databases in SQL Server, one of which is called MessageBox database which is responsible for routing, queuing, instance management, and a variety of other tasks.

When BizTalk Server receives a message, it processes the message in a pipeline, and places the message in the MessageBox database. When a process subscribes to this message, the MessageBox database sends the message to the process, which in turn processes the message on a host instance.

The MessageBox database saves the host instance’s state (among other data). So, if your host instance crashes or worse yet, Biztalk server crashes, the state of the instance is safeguarded in that database. When Biztalk resumes, the host instance resumes based on the information on the MessageBox database.

So answering your question, a message is never lost within the Biztalk Server in that situation.

> What is the result if biztalk own the message but the consumer
>   application(B) is down? will biztalk will hold the message till the
>   application(B) read the message once it is up?

This is actually configurable within Biztalk server. You can configure it to retry the send request (based on number of retries, time, etc. etc).

You can find more information on this subject on the following links (MSDN Library):

MessageBox Database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa562016.aspx

Biztalk Databases: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa578342.aspx

Biztalk Subscrition Architecture: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa560414.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the help...Now I'm able to understand the result(s) of the scenarios I have posted.